# Javascript to jQuery translation

Tags: javascript, jquery, code-translation

I have just started studying jquery and javascript and have encountered a line of code that I dont know how to translate. Any help would be much appreciated. Id like to translate it from JavaScript to jQuery so that I can use classes.
 Here are the lines of code.

```
    var rgb = getAverageRGB(document.getElementById('try'));
document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb('+rgb.r+','+rgb.g+','+rgb.b+')';
```

Comment: what is `getAverageRGB` doing there?

Comment: getaverageRGB is a function later defined in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing things up with that second line:

```
$('.post').css("background-color", 'rgb('+rgb.r+','+rgb.g+','+rgb.b+')');
```

And the jQuery way to find an element by its "id" value is

```
var rgb = getAverageRGB($('#try')[0]);
```

The `$('#try')` part creates a jQuery-wrapped list of nodes that match the selector, so in this case it'll be just one node. However, presuming that API expects a DOM node and not a jQuery wrapper, the trailing `[0]` extracts the raw DOM node from the jQuery wrapper.

Keep in mind that jQuery **is** JavaScript — we're not talking about two different languages.

Comment: Thanks for that line of code. It works fine :) Would you know how to translate the first one though?

Comment: @Fyxerz answer extended.

Comment: its not its the name of the function it was given. I am trying to translate it from this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MUsT8/